# Deferred Promise & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, promise, deferred

I read a lot of answers about deferred but cannot exactly find what I want.

The close piece of code is http://jsfiddle.net/UZzeC/

Difference in my code is that I want to call on "process" function inside the when. statement N number of times.

```
//Dynamically generated JSON list
var json_list = [
    {"id":"div1","name":"Google.com"},
    {"id":"div2","name":"eBay.com"}
    {"id":"div3","name":"Yahoo.com"},
    {"id":"div4","name":"Facebook.com"}
];

$.when(
    for (var i in json_list) {
        process(json_list[i].id, json_list[i].name),
    }
).done(function() {
    $('#global').text("OK"); }
) .fail(function() {
    $('#global').text("FAIL");
});
```

the end state will be the code connecting to multiple web services async and returning its progress when each comes back with data

Can I embed this loop like this? I saw some usage on "Apply" with when but not sure how it would work for me.

Comment: `var i in json_list` will go through properties on the prototype as well.

Comment: Use json_list.hasOwnProperty(i) to prevent calling process on the prototype properties

Comment: @agconti it will only go through the _enumerable_ properties.  On moderns browsers there won't be any that the coder didn't put there themselves.

Comment: In any case, `json_list` is actually an array not an object so the code shouldn't use `for .. in` at all!

Comment: thanks everyone for your contributions. To give you a better visual, I created a not so perfect JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/b23aoe52/1/

Comment: Just want to show the intention here where user somehow executes the code in what order and I get an Windows like application behavior of multi-threading... I realize the code is far from working condition, etc

Comment: jsfiddle.net/b23aoe52/3 - work in progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this...
(supposing process return a $.Deferred().promise() object)

```
var requests = [];

for (var i=0; i<json_list.length; i++) {
    requests.push(process(json_list[i].id, json_list[i].name));
}

$.when.apply($, requests).then(
    function() { $('#global').text("OK"); },
    function() { $('#global').text("FAIL"); }
);
```

**EDIT:** Edited the code to iterate the array properly. I thought it was an object and used for..in, but you should use this way always ;)

Comment: By the way, since you are using jQuery you can replace the for..in with $.each

Comment: thanks danikaze for the very quick response! I will try this out but seems like this will do the trick.

Comment: @danikaze and FWIW, jQuery's `.each` _doesn't_ use a `hasOwnProperty` test.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't know about jQuery's insides, but if you want compatibility with IE8 while using a for..in loop, you need to use hasOwnProperty

Comment: jQuery explicitly documents (_somewhere_) that it will not work if `Object.prototype` has been unsafely extended.  In any event, the OP has an array not an object so shouldn't be using `for .. in` at all!

Comment: @ChrisP don't - use `.map` or `$.map` instead.  The entire point of those functions is to create a new array based on an existing an array that has been transmuted via a function.  Almost any time you see `var a = []; for (.....) { a.push}` you should be using `a.map` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Only in very exceptional circumstances (practically, *never*) should `for(var i in arr) {...}` be used to loop through an array. The reason is that an array may have properties other than its numeric array indices, that not even `if(arr.hasOwnProperty(i))` will filter out.

For example :

```
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
arr.color = 'RED';
```

Now, loop through `arr` with `for(var i in arr)` and you will discover `A`, `B`, `C`, and `RED`. ie the array's *members* and its *properties*.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raxp9L76/)**

To be guaranteed to address just the array members, loop with `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {...}`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raxp9L76/1/)**

So, you can do as follows :

```
var requests = [];
for(var i=0; i<json_list.length; i++) {
    requests.push(process(json_list[i].id, json_list[i].name));
}

$.when.apply(null, requests).then(function() {
    $('#global').text("OK");
}, function() {
    $('#global').text("FAIL");
});
```

You can also use the native `Array.prototype.map()` or `jQuery.map()` to loop through the original array and return a processed array. For compactness, the processed array can be passed anonymously to `$.when`, as follows :

```
$.when.apply(null, $.map(json_list, function(request) {
    return process(request.id, request.name);
}).get()).then(function() {
    $('#global').text("OK");
}, function() {
    $('#global').text("FAIL");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you can pass a jQuery object from `$.map` directly to `.apply` without calling `.get()` first?

Comment: @Alnitak, my mistake - yes `.get()` is necessary, thank you, edited.

Comment: @ChrisP you haven't passed `json_list` into the code in the final example.

Comment: yea, sorry Alnitak - I didnt complete the example properly where the button actually calls the function properly and the JSON is properly referenced. let me see if I can clean it up a bit and post an updated example again.

Comment: I took the suggestions and made the new example a bit more complete (not perfect)   http://jsfiddle.net/b23aoe52/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `for .. in` on arrays
2. You can't substitute a `for` loop for a function parameter - JS doesn't work that way

Since your `json_list` is an array, you can just use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get a new array of Promises, one for for each entry in the original array:

```
var requests = json_list.map(function(l) {
    return func_returning_promise(l.id, l.name);
});
```

and then you can use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass this array of Promises to `$.when` as if they were individual parameters:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(okFunc, failFunc);
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `jQuery.map(fn)` has a potentially useful feature missing from the native `Array.prototype.map()` - namely that, in the former, returning `null` from `fn` omits that would-be member from the output array. In the latter, you get member == null. For this reason it's useful to have both methods in your locker.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'd call that a bug, not a feature ;-)   If I want to remove `null` items I'd call `.filter` first

Comment: I will always find it hard to see it that way given that jQuery.map was in from the start, v1.0, some 5 years before Array.prototype.map hit the streets at ES 5.1 ! (But please note, I didn't say you're wrong).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 fair comment, but `map`-like functions have been a staple of functional languages for decades but AFAIK only jQuery's has this "return null" feature.

Comment: I bow to superior knowledge of other functional languages (except possibly APL if that counts).